# android list view image addition

Tags: android

holder.text.setText(DATA[position]);
            holder.icon.setImageBitmap((position &1) == 1 ? mIcon1 : mIcon2);

```
        return convertView;
    }
```

The following code above lets me display only icons 1 and 2, I have added other images but dont know how to add those icons to the listview.

Any help would appreciated as I am just new here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for but you can try something like this.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
     super.onCreate(icicle);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     setListAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this));
     selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);
}

class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
      Activity context;

      CustomAdapter(Activity context) {
            super(context, R.layout.row, items);
            this.context=context;
      }

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      View row=convertView;
        if (row==null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
            row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }

        TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.label);
        label.setText(items[position]);
        ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
       //you can put your own logic to add images here
        if (items[position].length()>4) {
            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete);
        }
        else {
            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);
        }
          return(row);
        }
   }
```

Comment: Want I want to try and do is add an image to every row. So what would I need? appreciate it.

Comment: Hi danish, what do you mean with add image to every row ? Did you try the code above ? There is param 'position' at View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent). You can set your row image based on index position there.